# Java WatchService doesn't work on some folders

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, filesystems, watchservice

I want to use [Java 7 WatchService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) to monitor `/proc` folder, but that's not working (changes made in the folder are not reported). I've tested other folders such as `/home/user/Desktop` and `/tmp` and it works. What could be the reason? Is it because of permissions? `/proc` is obviously owned by root whereas the other folder is owned by logged in user. The `/tmp` however is also owned by root, but it works. I'm using [this basic implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html#try) to test it.

My OS is Ubuntu 13.10 64bit. Oracle Java 1.7.0_51.

Answer (score 1):

It's because /proc isn't a normal filesystem and therefore doesn't support inotify:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90627/notify-of-changes-on-a-file-under-proc
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74713/how-frequently-is-the-proc-file-system-updated-on-linux?rq=1