# NIO watchservice for UNIX sys/classes/gpio files

Tags: java, nio, gpio, watchservice

Is it possible to set the JAVA NIO WatchService on files in the `/sys/class/gpio/gpioX` device tree to supervise changes there ?

It would be nice idea to detect changes on the GPIO files (i.e. the GPIO -inputs) directly from within Java, but I fear that is not supported.

A confirmation that it's not supported (and perhaps why) would be sufficient.

Comment: Any luck with this? Do you need any more info?

Answer (score 6):

The linux implementation of the Java 7 NIO FileWatcher uses inotify. Inotify is a linux kernel subsystem to notice filesystem changes. It has restrictions and doesn't work on /proc, /sys and network shares. Please read [inotify limitations on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify#Limitations) :

> Inotify does report some but not all events in sysfs and procfs.
>
> Notification via inotify requires the kernel to be aware of all
>   relevant filesystem events, which is not always possible for networked
>   filesystems such as NFS where changes made by one client are not
>   immediately broadcast to other clients.

and a bit more:

[inotify missing events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17464364/3800377)
[Java WatchService doesn't work on some folders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23568842/3800377)
[Java WatchService not generating events while watching mapped drives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12494547/3800377)

Comment: That's pretty interesting. I figured that it wouldn't work on things like /proc and /sys, but I'd expect network filesystems to be able to implement it assuming the protocol permits for it.

Comment: @Trejkaz it's sad but true. kernel can't control network filesystem. FYI: i've improved my answer